# Need help with Entity Framework Relationshipships

Tags: entity-framework

I'm new to Entity Framework and just experimenting...

Consider 3 db tables where Person is a base table. I want the Employe table to enherit from Person, storing employee specific info. It seems that EF requires that PersonId also be the PK of the Employee table, so I made EmployeeID a unique index.

Next I added a table, Application, which stores one record for every software application that the Employee supports, creating a foreign key from Application.EmployeeId to Employee.EmployeeId.

However, EF doesn't seem to recognize relationships that involve unique indexes, but only Primary Keys.

What I can do is create a relationship from Application.PersonId to Person.PersonId, however, only Employees can be responsible for an Application, so it seems more natural to me to have Application as a "child" of the Employee table rather than the Person table.

Is this possible in EF?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you doing database first ?

Comment: yes, I am using database first, although I was trying to modify the model and see what database canges it generates so i can "reverse engineer" what I needed to do when doing db first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build your relation between `Employee` (`PersonId`) and `Application` (`EmployeeId`). In such case the integrity should work as you expect because only `PersonId`s in `Employee` table will be only for existing employees. EF has currently no support for unique keys.

Comment: I don't think. PersonId is not in the Employee object in the model, omly in the Employee db table. It is only in the base class of Eployee, Person. This leads me to believe that I can only establish a relationship in th emodel between Person and Application, not between Employee and Application.

Comment: What will happen if you configure that relation in the database as I described and simply use update from database?

Comment: When I did that, the model picked up the relation. However, this isn't exactly what I wanted because this forces me to assign Employee ID values that are the same as PersonId. I would prefer to have a seperate pool of numbers for each. Perhaps my Person table contains millions of people and I only have a small number of employees...It's looking to me like it didn't take long (my first hello world example) to find a limitation of EF. Disappointing...

Comment: Looks like this confirms that you can't do what I want to do and that support for unique keys is the #1 requested feature: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2011/03/09/unique-constraints-in-the-entity-framework.aspx

Comment: But I wrote you that you should not build realation on EmployeeId but on PersonId.

Comment: Not sre I understand..You said to "build your relation between Employee (PersonId) and Application (EmployeeId)." For this to work, the values in the App.EmpId column must be equal to those in the Emp.PersonId column. To join on Emp.PersonId = App.EmpId, the values of PersId must  = EmpId. I want to have 2 separate pool of numbers for Emp Id and Person Id

Comment: EmployeeId is some unique identification of emplopee, isn't it? It is absolutely ok to have it only in Employee table and build relation with application against PersonId. If you need to know employeeId from application you can always get it through join (navigation property in EF).